# AWS node SDK cloud watch returns zero datapoints

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to fetch the bucket sizes (BucketSizeBytes) of my S3 buckets via Cloud Watch `getMetricStatistics`.

I feel like I've got everything set up, but the SDK returns no datapoints:

```
{ ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'ad520gfd4-7764-11e7-8084-2718255a18ba' },
  Label: 'BucketSizeBytes',
  Datapoints: [] }
```

I've setup a node app that runs the following code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
const cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();

var startTime = new Date(2017, 07, 15);
var endTime = new Date(2017, 08, 01);

var params = {
  EndTime: endTime,
  MetricName: 'BucketSizeBytes',
  Namespace: 'AWS/S3',
  Period: 3600,
  StartTime: startTime,
  Dimensions: [
    {
      Name: 'StorageType',
      Value: 'StandardStorage'
    }
  ],
  Statistics: [
    'Average'
  ],
  Unit: 'Bytes'
};

cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics(params, function(err, data){

    if(err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }

});
```

I've double checked my region in the config file, which is set to Frankfurt (eu-central-1), and to make sure, I even tried connecting to S3 in the same file which listed my buckets as expected:

```
var S3 = new AWS.S3();

S3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
  if (err) { console.log("Error:", err); }
  else {
    for (var index in data.Buckets) {
       var bucket = data.Buckets[index];
       console.log("Bucket: ", bucket.Name, ' : ', bucket.CreationDate);
    }
  }
});
```

I've also tried setting the exact same startDate and endDate in the AWS cloud watch interface to ensure that it had data. It did. So I just don't understand why I'm not getting any datapoints back? Any ideas on what I could do to fix it?

Comment: I usually find it helpful in cases like this to turn to aws-cli and start with a simple request that returns far more results than I want, then figure out how to add parameters one at a time to get fewer results until I have what I want.  Once you find what you need from the CLI, it translates pretty easily into any other SDK, since they are all ultimately talking to the same back-end service APIs.  Give that a shot?

Comment: This helped me find the problem. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem lies with my Date variables. I'm still getting used to the weird fact that Javascript dates are 0-based, so I was actually trying to get data from a date range in the future (embarrassing). Replacing the date variables with the following solved it:

```
var startTime = new Date(2017, 06, 19); // 2017-07-18T22:00:00.000Z
var endTime = new Date(2017, 07, 02); // 2017-08-01T22:00:00.000Z
```

A big thank you to [Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) for the tip. Having to type it into the aws cli forced me to type out the date values, and I got back the results I expected.

Comment: Hi, I am just wondering if the `Period: 3600` setting works for you? I tried the same configuration with AWS JS SDK and also the CLI, it only returned data by day.